# SUPER privilege not defined for master user in Amazon MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, amazon-rds

I have created one medium instance on amazon rds in asia pecific (singapore) region. i have created my master user with master password. and it is working/connecting fine with workbench installed on my local PC. When, I am going to create function on that instance, it show me following error

> ERROR 1418: This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

At my instance, my variable (log_bin_trust_function_creators) shows OFF. now when I go to change with variable using

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

it gives me another error

> Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I don't know how to solve this error.

Can anybody help???

Answer (score 6):

You can try to change `log_bin_trust_function_creators`; however, there is an alternative approach that seems more appropriate when you consider the [meaning of that variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators):

> It controls whether stored function creators can be trusted not to create stored functions that will cause unsafe events to be written to the binary log.
>
> A setting of `0` also enforces the restriction that a function must be declared with the `DETERMINISTIC` characteristic, or with the `READS SQL DATA` or `NO SQL` characteristic. If the variable is set to `1`, MySQL does not enforce these restrictions on stored function creation.

All that option does is assume that you know what you are doing, without making you assert that you do by using one of the three characteristics in your `CREATE` statement... but if you don't properly declare the function, you may miss out on potential optimizations.

> misdeclaring a routine might affect results or affect performance

Taken together, this implies that the most correct approach is to declare your stored functions with `DETERMINISTIC` or `READS SQL DATA` or `NO SQL` as appropriate, and, if these do not correctly describe your function's behavior, then your function still may result in unsafe statements being written to the binary log, because [these options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) are also "trusted:"

> Assessment of the nature of a routine is based on the “honesty” of the creator: MySQL does not check that a routine declared `DETERMINISTIC` is free of statements that produce nondeterministic results.

---

Curious aside: astute observers will note that I omitted something from the documentation's description:

> If set to 0 (the default), users are not permitted to create or alter stored functions unless they have the `SUPER` privilege in addition to the `CREATE ROUTINE` or `ALTER ROUTINE` privilege.

Since nobody gets `SUPER` in RDS, and assuming this is not an error in the official documentation, this seems like it must be an AWS customization of MySQL behavior.